# Obter imagem de BLOB da base de dados usando Spring MVC + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html5, spring, thymeleaf, blob

Tenho problemas ao tentar apresentar uma imagem no frontend usando *Spring MVC* e *Hibernate* para retornar a imagem armazenada num *BLOB* na base de dados.

**Entity**:

```
@Lob
@Column(length = 100000)
private byte[] foto;

public byte[] getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}
```

**Controller**:

```
@GetMapping("/view")
    public ModelMap viewVehicle(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Vehicle vehicle, Model model) {
        if (vehicle == null) {
            vehicle = new Vehicle();
        }

        return new ModelMap("vehicle", vehicle);
    }
```

**HTML**:

```
<img th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+ foto}" />
```

Não tenho qualquer tipo de erro ao compilar ou correr a aplicação, nem mesmo acedendo a página em questão, no entanto a imagem não é apresentada.

Experimentei várias soluções apresentadas na Internet, mas sem sucesso em nenhuma delas.

Alguma consideração para me ajudar a resolver esta questão?

Comment: O idioma do site é **portugues**, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Então.... o conteúdo de um byte[] não é o mesmo de um base64